# Angular2 Reactive Form edit error

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

This is my create poll page. [image: ][1]]

This is my edit form. [image: ][2]]

When i click create poll button it work well but when i click edit button it shows all the value to be edited in form but it doesn't enable the button until i touch the input textbox and change some value on the input textbox.

The button editpoll on the edit form is disabled even all the values are filled in the form.
The editpoll button will be enabled only when i touch all the input text field and overwrite the value.

Comment: What is your question en what is your code

Comment: I am just trying to to  a edit operation.What i expect is that when i clicked  edit button it should enable the edit poll button but it  was disabled. It will be enabled only if i touched all the text box.

Comment: What is the condition you use to disable the button?

Comment: Again, show some code

Answer (score 1):

> The editpoll button will be enabled only when i touch all the input
>   text field and overwrite the value.

Look like to you button `disabled` attribute is binded to `pristine`:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="form.pristine && !form.valid" />
```

Update it to:

```
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the previous guy said, it'd be better if you'd share some piece code.

any way, according to your explanation it seem like it waits until your form marked as 'dirty'.
check again if there's no condition set for the [disabled] attr on the edit button elemnt.